# Match an arbitrary sequence that is repeated twice in a string

Tags: regex

I have a list of names. The names may have one, two or more parts. For example:

- Cher
- Humphrey Bogart
- Edgar Allen Poe

One of my input supplies is feeding me names where the name is repeated two times with a space in between.

- Cher Cher
- Humphrey Bogart Humphrey Bogart
- Edgar Allen Poe Edgar Allen Poe

Is there a regular expression that I can use to find the lines with the repeats?  And get it to give me the name (un-repeated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eP3wX9/2)

Short and simple:

```
([a-zA-Z ]+) (\1)
```

Comment: I needed to apply this to addresses so I used `([\w\. ]+) (\1)` to allow numbers and periods.  Works great in C#.

Comment: For `abc cba`, it finds a match at `c c`.  So it'll work for the examples because they start with an upper-case letter and end with a lower-case letter, but may false-positive for words that are all lower case.

Answer (score 3):

```
^(.*?)(?=\s\1)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/71

Comment: Thanks for the link to regex.  I am adding that to my tool box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to find all names with at least one repeated words:

```
(.+)\h+(?=\1)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR0rW6/4)

Comment: If you remove the trailing .*$ it works for the example given. Otherwise it only works in the 'Cher' case. See https://regex101.com/r/xR0rW6/1

Comment: It is working fine. You need `g` (global) and `m` (multiline) flags. [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR0rW6/2)

Comment: It still requires removing the .*$ at the end of the main expression. With the .*$ the second line matches 'Humphry', not 'Humphry Bogart'.    When the .* is removed the expression does the match I am looking for.

Comment: Well 2nd line matches because `Humphry` is there twice. If you inset `foo bar baz` in 2nd line [then it won't match](https://regex101.com/r/xR0rW6/3) Not sure where is the confusion.

Comment: The problem is that it does not match the entire repeating pattern. It is not supposed to match 'Humphry" it should match 'Humphry Bogart'.  The other solutions pull out the full match.

Comment: That last one is the result I am looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: ok answer updated with this regex and demo. You may accept the answer now.